# SettingWithCopyWarning when modifying a single column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I recently started using pandas for data manipulation. I'm getting the SettingWithCopyWarning when modifying a single column (striping spaces and removing characters) like so:

```
dframe['title'] = dframe['title'].str.strip()
dframe['title'] = dframe['title'].str.upper().replace([";", ":"], "", regex=True)
```

Previously I've imported an excel file and used `df.iloc[]` to select the columns I wanted to work with, and rename the columns. I've already tried assigning that `df.iloc[]` to a new variable and the warning keeps appearing. Since I'm just starting with pandas, I don't want to ignore the warning right away because, I imagine, there is a better way to do it.

**The warning:**

```
See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
  dframe['title'] = dframe['title'].str.upper().replace([";", ":"], "", regex=True)
c:/file.py:45: SettingWithCopyWarning:
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
```

Comment: does the warning go away if you split the `upper` and `replace` into separate calls?

Comment: No, it still gives me the warning for every line

Answer (score 1):

Try using [apply](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) instead of performing transformations directly to the slices.

Your code becomes:

```
dframe['title'] = dframe['title'].apply(lambda x: str(x).strip())
dframe['title'] = dframe['title'].apply(lambda x: str(x).upper().replace(":", "").replace(";", ""))
```

Comment: The second line does not work but i will consider using lambda in the future. Also,  I figured  out why I was getting the error: I was modifying a slice that was not a copy of the original, thus the warning. Is there a way to marked as resolved or should I delete the question? I used `copy()` in the prior slice and the warning disappeared

Comment: Sorry about that, should have tested.  Not sure why replace stopped cooperating; the second line is fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be able to get rid of the warning if you apply .loc on both sides.

```
dframe.loc[:, 'title'] = dframe.loc[:, 'title'].str.strip()
```

Please let me know if it works as this warning has been a pain for me many times and must to be to many others :)